Rename column depending on the name of the previous column
I have ti combine files with columns of sales and quantities.
Each file contains 2 or 3 years of data. Example of a file columns:
Customer | sales 2010 | quantities | sales 2011 | quantities
The problem is that the name quantities contains no year. I would like to rename the columns in order to get quantities 2010, quantities 2011, etc.
So taking the 4 digits from the name of the previous column and concatenate it with the string quantities.
Of course, in power query.
I tried the following:
For each table, this means in the “Transform file” step ==>
Get the column names in a list
Access to the previous value with the index column method
Concatenation of the words quantities and the digits of the previous column name
This works but it is fastidious
Is there a simpler M code?

the name, of course !

I like Sam's method but if you really want what you are asking for
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
NewNames= let z=Record.FieldValues(Source{0}), a= List.RemoveFirstN(z,1) in {z{0}}& List.Transform(List.Positions(a),each if _=0 then a{0} else if Number.IsOdd(_) then a{_}&" "& Text.AfterDelimiter(a{_-1} ," ") else a{_}),
Rename=Table.RenameColumns(Table.RemoveFirstN(Source,1),List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source),NewNames}))            
in Rename



If by simpler you mean fewer steps, I don't think so.
Here is how I would do it.
Assuming the columns (after being brought into PQ where you cannot have two columns with the same name) always have a Sales column with the year followed by the related quantity column (with or without intervening columns) and any number of pairs:

I would do the following (replacing code after the #"Changed Type" step generated when you read in the CSV file.

Generate a List of all the Sales columns and extract the date based on transition from non-digit to digit
Generate a list of all the Quantity columns based on the name starting with Quant
Generate a list of Rename arguments by Ziping the above
Apply the Renames using the Table.RenameColumns function

    #"Column Renames" = 
        let 
            #"All Columns" = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
            #"Years" = List.Transform(
                List.Select(#"All Columns", (L)=>Text.StartsWith(L,"Sales")),
                each Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c)=>not List.Contains({"0".."9"},c),{"0".."9"})(_){1})
        in 
            List.Zip({  
                        List.Select(#"All Columns",each Text.StartsWith(_,"Quant")), 
                        List.Transform(#"Years", each "Quantity " & _)
                    }),
   
    #"Rename Qty Cols" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",#"Column Renames")     
in
    #"Rename Qty Cols"



I would recommend aiming to have one column for Sales, one for Quantity, and one for Year. Here is a suggested approach.
With a starting file/table like so:


Select Customer column, and Unpivot Other columns
Select Column (or Attribute) column and split on {space} to get the Year
Select the column again and split by _ to normalize the quantity column
Remove the excess column from step 3
Fill-down the Year column
Finally, Pivot on the Column column

let
  Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("..\example.csv"), [Delimiter = ",", Columns = 5, Encoding = 65001, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.None]),
  #"Promoted headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars = true]),
  #"Unpivoted other columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Promoted headers", {"cutomer"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
  #"Split column by delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted other columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" "), {"Column", "Year"}),
  #"Split column by delimiter 1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split column by delimiter", "Column", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_"), {"Column", "Column.2"}),
  #"Removed columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split column by delimiter 1", {"Column.2"}),
  #"Filled down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed columns", {"Year"}),
  #"Pivoted column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled down", {{"Column", type text}}), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled down", {{"Column", type text}})[Column]), "Column", "Value")
in
  #"Pivoted column"


To hopefully give you a resulting table looking like:

